# Rewrite haystack array into new array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, url-rewriting

i have a big array that every month has weeks, and every weeks i have users, and every user have 3 differents totals. Check out:

```
Array //REPRESENTS THE MONTH
(
    [0] => Array //REPRESENTS THE WEEK 1 
        (
            [week] => 1
            [user1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
            [user2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
            [user3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array //REPRESENTS THE WEEK 2
        (
            [week] => 2
            [user1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
            [user2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
            [user3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [total1] => value
                            [total2] => value2
                            [total3] => value3
                        )
                )
        )
    ...
```

I want make one array that get the values of the users and unify in one array, like this:

```
Array
( 
    [user1] => Array
    (
        [total1] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
        [total2] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
        [total3] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
    )
    [user2] => Array
    (
        [total1] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
        [total2] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
        [total3] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
    )
    ...
) AFTER SUM THIS VALUES AND PUT IN VARIABLES $total1, $total2, $total3
```

How i do that?

Comment: And what you have tried so far. And what you mean by `totalWeek1` can you please elaborate

Comment: what the difference between total1, total2... in the second array?

Comment: @splash58 is the users. Every user has your values.

Comment: I am about this for one user `[total1] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'...
        [total2] => 'totalWeek1', 'totalWeek2', 'totalWeek3'`

Comment: @Uchiha i want rewrite for every user, all the values of the weeks and after sum them.

Comment: i've written a code in my answer. but not from the desktop so cant test ^(